# webpack-dev-server can't detect file changes in nested folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack-dev-server v1.14.1 for my project and the whole project structure is as follows:

```
|----src
|     |----index.js
|     |----components
|     |     |----a.js
|     |----containers
|           |----sub-containers
|                 |----b.js 
|     
|----package.json
|----webpack.config.dev.js
```

However, when I run command "webpack-dev-server --inline", the server can only catch changes in a.js file. It ignores changes in b.js file.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Which operating system do you have? I've found that the webpack dev server's change detection is very flaky in Windows since it doesn't use a full-fledged file system watcher. I doubt it's related to the nesting structure, but rather the fact that it doesn't consistently work.

Comment: @Jacob I'm on Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks)

Comment: Maybe the file watching is just as bad? Just to make sure, try making a change, saving, making a change, saving, multiple times. Sometimes I have to spam a file with updates before the dev server notices. Just want to rule out that it's actually related to your file structure, which I have not observed.

Comment: yeah, tried that multiple times and the results are consistent. It always fails to catch changes in a.js but can detect changes in b.js succesfully. I also tried make changes in a.js's sibling files, got same results. This is also the first time for me to see this nesting structure issue. @Jacob

Comment: How do you import `b.js`?

Comment: @Everettss In src/index.js, I'm using ES6 syntax to import b.js like this: 
import b from "./containers/sub-containers/b";

Comment: @Everettss nvm, I was stupid. just find that I used capitalized "B" when importing "b.js". It was like: import B from "./containers/sub-containers/B". Now it works after changing it to: import B from "./containers/sub-containers/b". What surprised me is webpack didn't complain about my old import and can still resolve it. Only hot reloading didn't work :(

Comment: It happens all the time. In the future: https://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/mis314/lectures/images/rubber-duck-debugging.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Problem solved! It was caused by wrong import in src/index.js file. I imported b.js wrong way:

```
import B from "./containers/sub-containers/B";
```

I capitalized the file name "b". However, webpack didn't complain about this and could resolve this import. It only made hot reloading for changes in b.js not work. After changing it to:

```
import B from "./containers/sub-containers/b"
```

it works now! :)

NOTE: I'm still curious about why webpack can resolve the wrong filename. Or is it case insensitive?

Comment: @MrJSingh Self answering one's own question is totally encouraged. There is no problem in letting other people know what was your problem. In this very case, I am happy OP could put their answer, it helped me solve my problem. Please don't advice against self answering again.

Comment: Had exactly this same problem too. Refactored a folder to start with a lowercase instead of a Capital. Everything was still working, so didn't care to double check my imports. -.-'  Guess it could've taken me a while to find it out that I missed that. Thanks :p